Horizontal/column Itemization
Is there a way to use Itemize to go right to left and cycle down the page instead of just going horizontally downward?
Thanks


Take a look to the package tasks.

Thanks Fran. Could you clarify/expound?  ''look to the package'' tasks?

I mean search in the manual of this package. See the example in my answer.


\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}
\begin{document}
\begin{tasks}[label={\bfseries\arabic*}.,start=23,label-width=4ex,column-sep=1em](4)
\task the first
\task the second
\task the third
\task the fourth
\task*(2) the fifth item is way too long for this 
and needs three columns % or two
\task the sixth
\task the seventh
\end{tasks}
\end{document}


I see. Thank you. I'll use this unless someone know how to it with the itemize environment :)

This works so well...goodbye itemize

ConTeXt provides an option to create horizontal columns with the itemizeenvironment.
\starttext

\startitemize[n,horizontal,three]
\startitem first element \stopitem
\startitem second element \stopitem
\startitem third element \stopitem
\startitem fourth element \stopitem
\startitem fifth element \stopitem
\startitem sixth element \stopitem
\stopitemize

\stoptext

It is important for this option to enclose the content of each item with \startitem and \stopitem.

